# How to transfer sensor information from galaxy watch 6 to own app

Tags: android, sdk, samsung-mobile, google-fit, galaxy

I am trying to build a mobile/wear app that communicates between my Galaxy Watch 6 and my phone. I would like to send sensor information like heart rate from my Wearable directly to my phone.

I didn't find a way to get the data directly without any other apps in between.

Ways and corresponding problems I found to do it:

1. Samsung Privileged Health SDK: You need to request a partnership
2. Samsung Health SDK: Data runs through the Samsung Health app, which could be a problem with data privacy
3. Android Health/Health Connect: Data runs through the Health Connect app, which could be a problem with data privacy
4. Google Fit/Fitness API: Data runs through the Google Fit app, which could be a problem with data privacy

Any Ideas or things I get wrong?